# Method returning the very entity itself(which is not a JavaBean method), will be recognized as unmapped property(in gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, mapstruct

I define an abstract class and its implementation as follows.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(CRUDListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAR<A extends AbstractAR<A, ID>, ID> extends AbstractAggregateRoot<A> implements DomainEntity<A, ID> {

    public void validate() {
    }

    protected boolean enableSelectEvent() {
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public A update(Consumer<A> updater) {
        A a = (A) this;
        updater.accept(a);
        return a;
    }

}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = SimpleDO.TABLE_NAME)
public class SimpleDO extends AbstractAR<SimpleDO, String> {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "simple_table";

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    @Comment("name")
    private String name;

}
```

When i using Mapstruct with Gradle project will cause a compilation error(Unmapped target property: "update"), which is obviously not a JavaBean method. It means I have to explicitly declare to ignore the target property(update) in order to compile successfully.

> Tips: I can successfully compile and run the same code in maven project with the same version of Mapstruct(1.4.2.Final).

What caused the differences between Gradle and Maven?

```
// My gradle script
dependencies {
        implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct'
        implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

        annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding'
        annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct'
        annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor'
        annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8'

        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8'
    }
```

```xml
<!-- My maven pom.xml -->
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
              <version>0.2.0</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

I have try mapstrcut version 1.5.5.Final and 1.4.2.Final.
When i declare `@Mapping(target = "update", ignore = true)` on mapping method, my project is runnable. Seems not a build configuration problem.

Comment: Your gradle script doesnt contain the version of each dependency. Are they really the same?

Comment: Yes, i can make sure there using the same version.  I'm actually not post the whole script on this page. 
```
    configurations.configureEach {
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
            if (it.requested.getGroup() == 'org.mapstruct' && it.requested.getName().startsWith('mapstruct')) {
                it.useVersion('1.4.2.Final')
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the cause...

By default, Gradle outputs logs at the warn level, while Maven(maven-compiler-plugin) does not.

And I raised the Gradle compilation warning level to the error level by setting`options.compilerArgs << "-Werror"`.